# Underbrace not looking like it is supposed to

Tags: math-mode, underbrace

I am trying to use underbraces and the file compiles, but doesn't look "right". Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[left=1.65cm,right=1.65cm,top=2.45cm,bottom=2.60cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amscd,amsbsy,mathabx,array,color}
\usepackage{mathtools}
        \usepackage{fancyhdr,framed,latexsym,multicol,pstricks,slashed,xcolor,multicol}
\usepackage{picture}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks,
citecolor=black,
filecolor=black,
linkcolor=black,
urlcolor=black
}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[Conny]{fncychap}

\begin{document}

$\underbrace{x + \cdots + x}_{n\rm\ times}$

\end{document}
```

Thanks for any help,

Michael D

Comment: This seems to result from a conflict between `amthabx` and the other maths fonts (amssymb, amsbsy). If you need only some glyphs from mathabx, it is possible to use them without loading the package, so you shouldn't load it.

Comment: OK. I think the only thing I needed from that Bernard, was the symbol "napprox" for not equivalent to as in set equality in discussing finite and infinite sets. Is there another way to obtain that symbol? Thanks so much!

Comment: You should see in the Comprehensive LaTex Symbol list : http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The problem is an incompatibility between `mathabx` and `mathtools`.

The latter redefines `\underbrace` and `\overbrace`, but it turns out that `mathabx` needs the original definition.

Just add

```
\let\underbrace\LaTeXunderbrace
\let\overbrace\LaTeXoverbrace
```

before `\begin{document}`.

[image]

Move the loading of `hyperref` last and get rid of unused packages.

<sub>I can't resist, sorry, but the chapter styles provided by `fncychap` are among the uglier I've seen in my life. Conny is not the worst, but the “all uppercase” is really bad (unless the letters are spaced out) and the big black band reminds obituaries).</sub>